# Importing CSV Files with Date Columns

Tags: import, csv, oracle-apex

I am working on a project that involves importing data via Apex's data workshop. Two of my columns contain dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`. Can anyone tell me how to get Apex to import these columns correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at the TO_DATETIME('My_String', 'My_Format_String'). Something like TO_DATETIME('2014-10-05 15:23:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') should work - note: not tested - don't have Oracle running here. Check the links [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm#i1003589) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Comment: where would the date_time function go...in first row of the csv or in the format field of the name mapping screen of the data upload wizard

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know how Apex's data workshop functions - I have a feeling that it's the mapping bit. Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL4219) which may help. If you don't get assistance here, you could try the Oracle Apex forums?

Comment: Apex is a development tool; this is a development question and belongs on Stack Overflow.